# what is the MySQL connection collation for the mongolian language?

Tags: mysql, collation

what is the MySQL connection collation for the mongolian language? utf8_unicode_ci? or ut8_general_ci?

Answer (score 1):

They should both cover the mongolian language.

The main difference is just in performance and sorting accuracy. utf8_general_ci is a bit faster than utf8_unicode_ci. utf8_unicode_ci on the other hand is a bit more accurate for sorting.

Comment: I have too many problems on my site. The content of meta description is not displayed correctly. Everything okay if i typed text in latin cyrillic, but not okay in cyrillic alphabet.what can be problem? i don't want to list the domain publicly. is there any way to send u private text by using this site. I'm new here as u seen my status. thanks

Comment: i think the browser doesn't recognize the Mongolian alphabet that i must use for this site. Seems okay the HTTP header, charset, and language. Also i created a collation using utf8_general_ci. Hopes no issues with the script. what can be the problem? please advise. thanks

Comment: There can be many problems. In the script as well as in your html. If you want you can send the domain and the script to winpin@supnig.com and I'll have a quick look at it. Another way would be to look at other cyrillic sites and check their send headers/html/and script if available.